# javascript passing variables

Tags: javascript, variables, switch-statement

I basically need to write a function that will get the value of certain variables, pass them and count a total price of an order. I'm using switch because for each case of chosen component the price will be different. And since I am very far from being an expert in JavaScript and messed up code probably.

Here's the whole js I wrote :

```js
(function(RamPrice, CPUPrice, HDDPrice, additionalHardDrivePrice, flashDrivePrice, additionalFlashDrivePrice) {




    var ramTrans = document.forms['ramMemory'].elements['ram'];
  for (var i = 0, len = ramTrans.length; i < len; i++) {
    ramTrans[i].onclick = function() {
      var choosenRam = this.value;
      switch (choosenRam) {
        case 'GOODRAM DDR4 8GB (2133MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 219.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        case 'Kingston DDR4 SODIMM 8GB (2133MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 229.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        case 'Crucial DDR4 8GB (2133MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 229.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        case 'HyperX Impact DDR4 8GB (2400MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 249.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        case 'HyperX IMPACT BLACK DDR3 8GB (1600MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 189.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        default:
          var RamPrice = 0;
      }
    };

    ramTrans[i].onchange = function() {
      var choosenRam = this.value;
      switch (choosenRam) {
        case 'GOODRAM DDR4 8GB (2133MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 219.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        case 'Kingston DDR4 SODIMM 8GB (2133MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 229.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        case 'Crucial DDR4 8GB (2133MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 229.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        case 'HyperX Impact DDR4 8GB (2400MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 249.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        case 'HyperX IMPACT BLACK DDR3 8GB (1600MHz)':
          var RamPrice = 189.00;
          document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + this.value;
          break;

        default:
          var RamPrice = 0;
      }
    };
  }
  // disable submission of all forms on this page
  for (var i = 0, len = document.forms.length; i < len; i++) {
    document.forms[i].onsubmit = function() {
      return false;
    };
  }


  var finalPrice = RamPrice + CPUPrice + HDDPrice + additionalHardDrivePrice + flashDrivePrice + additionalFlashDrivePrice;
  document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 'Cena zamówienia: ' + finalPrice + 'PLN';


}());
```

It looks like the last part is messed up because if I set the variables by finger it display everything properly. Therefore I believe it might be an issue with passing the variables.

Thanks in advance.

Edit. As advised I made this JavaScript code taking less space and hopefully make it more readable. I also find an issue. Variable (in this case) RamPrice is being displayed properly only right after the switch. Whenever I try to use RamPrice out of 'for' statement, variable becomes unassigned or return NaN value.

Comment: I would advise you strip your code down to a minimum needed to ask/answer the question

Comment: In addition of @DarrenSweeney, please, read this **before** ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve **MINIMAL, COMPLETE AND VERIFIABLE EXAMPLE**

Comment: what means *"messed up"*?

Comment: @NinaScholz that may be not the best way of explanation. Problem is that the second part of each case works perfectly fine. The paragraph is being changed accordingly to what is clicked, but when it comes to the last part of the whole JavaScript file, those variables I wanted to be set during this switch seem not to work.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I did what you asked me. Problem unfortunately still occurs.

Comment: Where are you setting `CPUPrice` and `HDDPrice`? - they are not set in the switches

Comment: @DarrenSweeney they are set. Full code is provided on https://jsfiddle.net/0ghyb6zt/5/ there all variables are set.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a map/object/hash:

```
var prices = {
    'GOODRAM DDR4 8GB (2133MHz)' : 219,
    'Kingston DDR4 SODIMM 8GB (2133MHz)': 229,
    // etc
};
document.getElementById('ramMem').innerHTML = 'Pamięć RAM: ' + prices[choosenRam];
```

Then you can get rid of all the switches :)

Also if you want to return a value, you must use `return RamPrice;` at the end of the function (not sure if that's what you wanted to do there).

Comment: This part works. Pointed paragraph is changed every time radio button option is chosen.

Answer (score -1):

The issue can be resolved by moving the price calculation into a function, you can then call the function after each change.

Comment: An actual code example would vastly improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: Interesting, I previously requested the HTML so I would be able to see the issue, this was deleted by Brad Larson @BradLarson (no reason given). I then answer the question and get down marked for NOT showing code. System is a little weird :)

Comment: For clarity, you have assigned a function to the onclick event this function does not know how to recalculate your basket price. You need to add a call to a function that can work out the price, you also need to be aware that your variables need to be scoped properly in order for the recalculation to work.